# Memory carveouts questions

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, android-kernel

I am planning to allocate memory which is used by a different processor by making the calls specified in ion_heap_create functions.

Please see: https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-msm-mako-3.4-jb-mr1/drivers/gpu/ion/ion_heap.c

ion-heap used the following linux functions shown below header file:
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/genalloc.h#L78

Now, this piece of memory will be used by Another processor for its needs and Linux will not use these.

This is my understanding - So, My question is Will such a thing leave to fragmentation issues.

Suppose it is like this:
|--------------|
| Linux Memory |
|------------- |
| Carveouts    |
|------------- |
|Linux Memory  |

---

Question is How does linux handle such a scenario? Does Virtual memory subsystem know anything about the carveouts if so, how does it ensure that
linux process/kernel does not use the memory in the carveouts.